It there a better upper bound for $\max_{1\leq i \leq n}(a_{i}*b_{i})$?
I would like to give an upper bound for $\max_{1\leq i \leq n}(a_{i}*b_{i})$ which is related to $\max_{1\leq i \leq n}(a_{i})$. I know that $\max_{1\leq i \leq n}(a_{i})\max_{1\leq i \leq n}(b_{i})$ can be one of them, but is there any better bound?

I believe it is already the finest bound?

$$\max_{1\leq i \leq n}(a_{i}\cdot b_{i}) \le \max_{1\leq i \leq n}(a_{i})\cdot \max_{1\leq i \leq n}(b_{i})\tag{1}$$
The equality occurs if and only if there exists $k \in \{1,2,..,n \}$ such that $\cases{a_k = \max_{1\leq i \leq n}(a_{i})\\b_k=max_{1\leq i \leq n}(b_{i})}$ (for example, $(a_1,a_2, a_3) = (1,2,3)$ and $(b_1,b_2, b_3) = (4,5,6)$, we have $a_3 = \max\{a_1,a_2,a_3 \}$ and  $b_3 = \max\{b_1,b_2,b_3 \}$).
As the equality can occur, the upper bound $(1)$ is already the strictest one.

There are some dynamics involved. First, $\max a_i \cdot \max b_i$ is not always an upper bound. For instance, take $a_i =-2,-1$ and $b_i= -3,-2$ then
$$a_i \leq -1 \text{ and } b_i\leq -2$$
but $\max a_i b_i =6$, not $2$.
In fact, this bound is only acheived when all digits are non-negative.
What's going on is that you are producting two discrete sets to form a new discrete set, so the maximum of the product set is not-necessarily related to the original maximum of either of the producting sets.

Thank you for your answer! The case I want to figure out is when all digits are non-negative.
